Django Admin Keeps Failing
I recently created a new Django project using cookie cutter with docker. I use this regularly to setup my Django projects but recently I've had an issue where any new project I start will boot up and load correctly but for some reason the admin says page not found. I can login with my created super user and stay on the root /admin dashboard but when I try to click on any of the table links it automatically goes to a page not found. Has anyone else experienced this and if so how have you fixed this? All of the normal django functions ie. migrate, makemigrations... are working fine. I just can't view anything in the admin.
Could this be a docker issue? I've checked the logs in docker but haven't noticed anything important.

Would you mind sharing few more details? Maybe your main urls.py file?

It is hardly a docker issue, more likely to be a django issue, do you have     'django.contrib.admin', in your settings.INSTALLED_APPS ?
